# Big differences in Yahoo data contra Euronext, why?

Tags: historical-data

Downloaded all historical data for Oslo Stock Exchange from Yahoo Finance (yfinance), and picked a random stock to check if the data corresponds with what I see on different newssites.

If I look at NAS.OL from Yahoo at 2015-10-21, the close price is about 19911 with a volume of 4232.

But if I look at the data from Euronext (the owner of the exchange) the close price is about 9330 with a volume of 10122? This is also what I see in the different newssites here.

(Was just one action in 2020-12-18, a stock split of 0.01, according to Yahoo)

If I plot the graphs they look similar, but why is the difference in numbers so big?

(Edit: This has been marked as a duplicate, but the link to the other question is over 10 years old)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Yahoo! data is famously unreliable.

Comment: @BobJansen are there any other sources you recommend that are gratis? Are all the stock exchanges in EU required by law to provide this data gratis?

Comment: You can try this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/168/848). I don't know about the EU rules. I'm pretty sure they are not required to provide extensive history though because in that case you would be able to easily get it.

Comment: The answer is: 1) Yahoo! data is not a source professionals or academics use because the quality is bad. 2) We can only guess why a particular time series is bad and it will differ for each series so it is not generalizable and so does not make a good question for StackExchange. 1 and 2 combined make this a bad fit. If you don't agree I invite you to post on meta and make your case why question on the quality of free data is on-topic here.

Comment: @BobJansen What is the source professionals/academics use?

Comment: If you look at Yahoo, you will notice adj. close and close is identical throughout. If you download the history, you will see that the first big break occurs on Monday 4 May 2020. According to [euronext](https://live.euronext.com/en/listview/company-press-release/105827?combine=&field_company_pr_pub_datetime_start=1970-01-01%2000%3A00%3A00&field_company_pr_pub_datetime_end=now&page=4#CompanyPressRelease-3414099), A total of 2,978,402,828 new shares* will be issued .... The total number of shares in the Company after the debt conversion will hence be 3,141,775,135**....

Comment: Quick [comment to yahoo finance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUmRQCC61Vw&t=623s) by [Graham Giller](https://www.gillerinvestments.com/about). [Data cleaning](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66336/54838) is very important but trusted sources (which also have issues) are Bloomberg, Reuters and the like. It does not matter how old a link is, as long as nothing changed.